# iOS15 polyline does not show on mapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpolyline, ios15.2

I tried to add a polyline from the user's location to destination by using the following code, I am sure that I have conformed to the delegate and ensure that the user is in authorizedAlway mode in the authorization status. However, the console generated this error message saying "**[UserSession] maps short session requested but session sharing is not enabled**" I can not find anything related on how to solve this error.

```
    func generatePolyLine(toDestination destination: MKMapItem) {
    
    let request = MKDirections.Request()
    //start from the user's current location to find the ride
    request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    request.destination = destination
    request.transportType = .automobile

    let directionRequest = MKDirections(request: request)

    directionRequest.calculate { response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error calculating direction request \(error)")
        }
        guard let response = response else { return }
        self.route = response.routes.first
        guard let polyLine = self.route?.polyline else { return }
        self.mapView.addOverlay(polyLine, level: .aboveRoads)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Facing the same error. Have you got the issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the delegate method to specify the renderer? Something like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        renderer.alpha = 0.5
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        
        return renderer
    }
    if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {
        let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)
        renderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        renderer.alpha = 0.5
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        
        return renderer
    }
    return MKCircleRenderer()
}
```

Comment: yes i did.  It does not work either. `private func mapView (_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {                                                      
 if let route = self.route { let polyLine = route.polyline
            let lineRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: polyLine)
            lineRenderer.strokeColor = .mainBlueColor
            lineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
            return lineRenderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }`